# What is the number on the card that Person 2 has?

Tags: puzzle

I came upon a question that I was struggling on.

The question is:

A teacher has five cards, labelled 1,2,3,4,5. The teacher then takes two cards from the five cards, a gives them to two people.

The teacher then asks the first person:

> *Is your card number larger than the second person?*

The person responded:

> I don't know.

The teacher then asked the second person:

> *Is your card number larger than the first person?*

This person responded:

> I don't know.

The teacher then told the class:

> **What is the value of the second person's card?**

Someone answered it correctly. What is the number?

**What I know**

If both people had either 1 or 5 on their cards, then they would have said:

> No

or

> Yes

So that means we can eliminate 1 and 5, so the second person must have had 2,3,4.

**Problem**

How do we get to the conclusion that the second person has 2,3 or 4?

Comment: The second person can figure out that the first person doesn't have $1$ or $5$.  If he had a $4$, he'd know he had the highest card, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct... Coming to think of it

Comment: So can you finish it now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz you mind if you put it on the answers and I can accept it?... Just wondering

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that refers to the content of your question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Person $2$ doesn't have $1$ or $5$, and he can deduce that person $1$ does not.  If he had $4$, he'd know he had the higher card, and if he had $2$, he'd know he had the lower card.

The second person's card is $3$.